# Not able to read dtabase.sqlite file in iOS (No such table Z_METADATA)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration, encrypted-core-data-sql

In new version I start using Core Data. But when I try to migrate from an old database to the new one, I'm getting an error:

```
let dbName = "db.sqlite:"

guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Ex", withExtension: "momd"), 
      let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
    fatalError("model not found")
}

let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
let databaseUrl = URL.defaultUrl.appendingPathComponent(dbName)

do {
    try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, 
                    configurationName: nil, 
                                   at: databaseUrl, 
                              options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
} catch {
    fatalError("database migration error")
}

context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
```

Error message:

> ```
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file couldn’t be opened."
> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=I/O error for database at
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/dsdasda-6Basdsd9C-4AE9-sad-sd/Documents/db.sqlite.
> SQLite error code:1, 'no such table: Z_METADATA', NSSQLiteErrorDomain=1}
> error: The file couldn’t be opened.
> ```

How i can resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

The trailing colon in the `dbName` looks extraneous. ("db.sqlite**:**")